# c++ How to globally reference a variable

Tags: c++, variables, reference

I've come across a problem while referencing a global variable.

This is my variable that should be a reference:

```
Color &cRGBMenu = Color(0,0,0);
```

I have a function that has a parameter, which references to cRGBMenu;

```
    void RGBButton(int iYAdder, const char* szTitle1, const char* szTitle2, Color &col1, Color &col2, int parentWidth) {
    if (iCurrTab == _iTabIndex) {

        DrawFunctions::DrawFilledRectText(_iX, iY, iW * 4, iH, lightgrey, grey, MenuNew::tahoma12, szTitle1);
        DrawFunctions::DrawFilledRectText(_iX + (iW * 4.5), iY, iW * 4, iH, lightgrey, grey, MenuNew::tahoma12, szTitle2);

        if (OnCustomClick(_iX, iY, iW * 4, iH)) {
            cRGBMenu = col1;
            bRGBMenu = true;
        }

    }
}
```

So this works, cRGBMenu is a reference to col1 and it knows the values
whereas the parameter col1 is another Color.
The problem is, when i try to actually change the value. I failed to succeed.

I attempt it in this snippet:

```
option->RGBSlider(x, y += iTabWidth / 8, w, h, Color(255, 0, 0), cRGBMenu.r(), red);
option->RGBSlider(x, y += iTabWidth / 8, w, h, Color(0, 255, 0), cRGBMenu.g(), green);
option->RGBSlider(x, y += iTabWidth / 8, w, h, Color(0, 0, 255), cRGBMenu.b(), blue);
option->RGBSample(x, y += iTabWidth / 8, w, iTabHeight, cRGBMenu);
cRGBMenu.SetColor(red, green, blue, cRGBMenu.a());
```

cRGBMenu has the value of the earlier parameter, it has changed only locally. However, even though i made a reference (i guess), the cRGBMenu doesnt change the original variable that was the parameter.

I'm pretty new to referencing, i've done it multiple times within a function, which always succeeded. No idea what i'm doing wrong here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: use Color RgbMenu{0,0,0};  You don't want RgbMenu to be a reference, but a variable.

Comment: @ttemple Tying your way, i end up with the same result. my variable that i used as a parameter remains its value.

Comment: @ttemple And why wouldn't i want it to be a reference? RgbMenu should just be a reference to a variable since the variable differs.

Comment: Where is cRGBMenu declared?   At what scope?  And in what file?   In a header file? In the same .CPP file as the code you are talking about?

Comment: @Joe At the top of the file, so, no scopes. Everything that i provided is in the same .cpp file, except the Color class. It's a public class for RGB's in DirectX.

Comment: What is 'Color'?  Is it possible that the values in the Color class are const and can only be set on construction?

Comment: Color is a class with whereas most functions are const. However, with my function, i draw an RGB menu, that changes the colours and sets them. 'cRGBMenu.SetColor(red, green, blue, cRGBMenu.a());'

The problem is, cRGBMenu his colours are set,  but the original parameter i used, didn't change. and since i use that parameter to declare what cRGBMenu is, it immediately gets re-overwritten.

Comment: @peppah `cRGBMenu = col1;` is an *assignment*, it *copies the values* from `col1` into `cRGBMenu`, it *does not* make `cRGBMenu` refer to `col1` itself, if that is what you are attempting.  Once a reference has been initialized, it can't be changed to refer to something else. If you want that, you have to use a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: The main problem i think is that i am not even referencing cRGBMenu correctly. Otherwise i wouldnt have a problem. if i declare cRGBMenu to be:
Color &cRGBMenu = Color(0,0,0);
and i later assign  cRGBMenu = *Other colour variable*

I should be able to edit cRGBMenu while the *Other colour variable* gets modified aswell?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh thanks for the information. I'll look into it.

Comment: @peppah what you describe is not valid, and `Color &cRGBMenu = Color(0,0,0);` shouldn't even compile since a *non-const* reference cannot bind to an rvalue (aka a temporary object), which `Color(0,0,0)` is.

Comment: As Remey Lebeau pointed out, you can't reassign cRGBMenu to another Color variable after you initialize it to Color(0,0,0)

Comment: I suspect your overall approach is flawed. You want a global variable to point to a local parameter. What is supposed to happen to the global variable when that parameter's lifetime ends? Having a local point to a global is somewhat safe-ish, but a global pointing to a local is usually a crash waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Remey, i found out how it's supposed to be done.

Declaration:

```
Color* cRGBMenu = &Color(0,0,0);
```

Modifying cRGBMenu to a variable:

```
cRGBMenu = &col1;
```

Referencing:

```
Color &_cRGBMenu = *cRGBMenu;
```

Now _cRGBMenu is a pointer (or) reference to my col1.

Comment: That does not look right. You have declared `cRGBMenu` to be a pointer to a temporary object. The temporary dies at the end of that statement, leaving a dangling pointer in `cRGBMenu`.

Comment: Should i just remove its value?

Comment: If you remove its value, what is the point of having the variable? (My apologies if it seems like I'm being unhelpful, but you haven't mentioned what you are trying to accomplish. Without that, all anyone can say is that your approach is flawed and refer you to [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).)

Comment: That's really not at all how it is supposed to be done.  If this is all in one CPP file - (i.e. both the Color object and all use of it) -- then simply declare a global 'Color cRGBMenu(0, 0, 0)' and refer to it elsewhere in the file.  At no point do you need to use the reference symbol at all